# Python web crawling result is less than expected

Tags: python, html, selenium

I tried using Selenium to crawl the web data, it loads all 346 products after clicking on the load more button for a few times on the browser, however, it only shows 96 / 346 product instead of 346 / 346 product, any idea how to fix it? I have already put the crawling code right after the while true loop for clicking the load more button

[screen capture of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3w97V.jpg)

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import requests
import ast
from selenium import webdriver
driver=webdriver.Chrome('e:/Users/fungc1/Documents/chromedriver.exe')
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
options=Options()

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url="https://www.toysrus.com.sg/lego"


#data = soup.findAll('div',attrs={'class':'card-image-wrapper'})
#toc = soup.find_all('div',attrs={'class':'result-count text-center'})
driver.get(url)
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_link_text("STAY ON THE SINGAPORE SITE").click() 

while True:
    try:
                                      
        driver.execute_script("var scrollingElement = (document.scrollingElement || document.body);scrollingElement.scrollTop = scrollingElement.scrollHeight;")
        wait=WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.btn[data-url*='www.toysrus.com']"))).click()
        time.sleep(5)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        break
        time.sleep(5)
        
        
response = requests.get(url)
response_text = response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(response_text, 'lxml')
text = urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(text)

data = soup.findAll('div',attrs={'class':'card-image-wrapper'})
toc = soup.find_all('div',attrs={'class':'result-count text-center'})




emptylist2=[]
for item in toc:
    print((item).text.strip()[:-1])
    
    for div in data:
        links = div.findAll('a')
        for a in links:
            catalogueresult=ast.literal_eval("" + a['href'][1:-5][-7:])
        emptylist2.append(catalogueresult)
    print (emptylist2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing few things.
You opened the browser with Selenium and loaded all the items by clicking on load button. But after that you use requests library to request new html again from the url which has nothing to do with Selenium. So, you are doing two separate things. In your case even you remove the Selenium code you will get the same thing because you are not utilizing Selenium after loading all the products.

Now, what you need to do is to ask the Selenium to return the html code of all 396 products so that you can give it to BeautifulSoup for further parsing.

To do that, you don't need first 4 lines after your while loop ends. Do something like this:

```
html = driver.page_source #will return the html code with all products
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
```

With this you will get all 396 products.

Comment: i have voted you, but it says: Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded.